# java invalid method declaration; return type requied in init, run

Tags: java, url, exception, init, malformed

i'm making a mini java game and i got an error while compiling:

```
error:invalid method declaration;return type requied
public init() throws Exception {
       ^
```

First version was public void init, but i can't do like that because i need to use try{..}catch(Malformed...) or while compiling i got another error (needs catch blah blah).

This is code:

```
public void run() throws Exception{
try{
this.zz();
}catch(MalformedURLException me){
throw me;
}
this.zo();
}
```

Comment: public void init() throws Exception

Comment: public int init() throws Exception. Add the return type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
error:invalid method declaration;return type requied
public init() throws Exception {
      ^
// You are missing the return type
```

You forgot to add the return type to the method declaration. Every Java method should specify a return type . If it doesn't return anything to the caller , make it `void`. In your case it returns a primitive `int` , so declare `int` as return type.

Need to re factor your code a little :

```
// return type is int as you are returning primitive int `0`.
public int init() throws MalformedURLException {
    //...
    try{
     this.zx();
   }catch(MalformedURLException me){
    // log the Exception here
    // me.printStackTrace();
    // logger.error(... exception message ....);
    throw me;
    // in case you return 0 , in spite of the Exception 
    // you will never know about the exceptional situation
   }
   return 0;
 }
```

Refer [JLS 8.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4).

Comment: Yes but i can't use void because MalformedURLException is needed or url won't work.

Comment: @user2622574 I didn't get you . Please explain a bit more.

Comment: If i use void, i can't use return. I need to use try{...}catch MalformedURLException, because, this.zx has URL(file...).  try..catch malformed needs return

Comment: No it doesn't need return , you can simply throw the Exception .

Comment: error: run() in xray cannot implement run() in Runnable          public void run() throws Exception{                                             ............^

Comment: Show us some code , your error messages are not making sense without code !

Comment: If you have other issues, open a new question and be more specific with your code.  With respect to the question at hand, it has already been answered by multiple people...

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add the return type.  Since you're returning 0, I assume that you want to return an int.  So change your header to:

```
public int init() throws MalformedURLException
```

There's no reason to have `throws Exception`.  Be as specific as possible.

In general, the syntax for methods is:

**access modifier** (*public, protected, private*) **return type** (*primitive, object, void*) **method name**

Here's the Oracle tutorial on [Defining Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

Also, not sure if this applies, but if you only plan to return solely 0 or 1, for example, consider changing your method header to:

```
public boolean init() throws MalformedURLException
```

Answer (score 0):

Return type is mandatory. You have to provide one. No escape from this, I guess.